# rxjava with for each loop

Tags: android, rx-java2

I am trying to get the data from local db by each content asyncrounous,but the issue is that I want to get the data by the order that I retrieve,at first the data for the first conent,than the second etc.,currently I am getting the data in wrong order every time I run the code ,how can I achieve this?

```
 for (Content content : contents) {
                scoreCardDisposable = AppManagers.getContentManager()
                        .getScoreCardsAndUpdate(content.getId())
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .subscribe(scoreCards -> {
                           ...
                        });
                compositeDisposable.add(scoreCardDisposable);

           }
```

Comment: You'll need to use from iterable which is the equivalent of a for loop in rx java, once you get that you can use flatmap for the rest of it or you can probably skip the flatmap also.

Comment: @JudeFernandes can you please give some example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make an observable stream from a `List<>` you can use `Observable.fromIterable` operator:

```
compositeDisposable.add(Observable.fromIterable(contents)
            .flatMap(content -> {
                return AppManagers.getContentManager()
                        .getScoreCardsAndUpdate(content.getId());
            })
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(scoreCards -> {
                ...
            }));
```

**UPD**:

You can use a `zip` operator to combine content with the getScoreCardsAndUpdate result in custom object:

```
class Result {
    private String content;
    private String result;

    public Result(String content, String result) {
        this.content = content;
        this.result = result;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public String getResult() {
        return result;
    }
}

public Observable<String> getScoreCardsAndUpdate(String content) {
    return Observable.just("result = " + content);
}

@Test
public void test() {
    List<String> contents = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3", "4");

    Observable.fromIterable(contents)
            .flatMap(content -> {
                return Observable.zip(Observable.just(content), 
                        getScoreCardsAndUpdate(content), Result::new);
            })
            .subscribe(scoreCards -> {
                System.out.println("content = " + scoreCards.getContent() + 
                        ", " + scoreCards.getResult());
            });
}
```

Comment: Thx,can you please tell me how can I get `content` reference in `subscribe` ?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to process all the items in a single thread. You can achieve this by adding a scheduler in rxjava2

```
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.single())
```

Your code should be

```
for (Content content : contents) {
            scoreCardDisposable = AppManagers.getContentManager()
                    .getScoreCardsAndUpdate(content.getId())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.single())
                    .subscribe(scoreCards -> {
                       ...
                    });
            compositeDisposable.add(scoreCardDisposable);

       }
```

Comment: in getScoreCardsAndUpdate I already use subscribeOn(getIOScheduler()),should I change it?

Comment: yeah you will have to change it to any serial schedular so that your task gets executed one by one